# SharePoint Designer 2013 - few actions are missing for workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to query the list to get some information of particular ID but some actions are missing in SharePoint Designer 2013. I want following actions in SharePoint Designer.

[image]

But what it actually looks here in my screen :

[image]

I could not see Dictionary and HTTP actions in designer. I am new to this. Let me know if you have any suggestion to display these actions here.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow you created is a SharePoint 2010 workflow without OOB actions like call HTTP web service and etc. What you need is a SharePoint 2013 workflow. You have to set **Platform Type** to **SharePoint 2013 Workflow** when creating a new workflow.
[image]

If there is no SharePoint 2013 Workflow option under the dropdown menu, you have to configure workflow manager to get it. Reference: [Install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server).